# What is the price of a printing press?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pricing

What is the price of a [printing press](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipmenT/goods-and-services/books-paper-writing-supplies/#Printing_Press)?

Trying to be a writer, a printing press will help make multiple copies of adventure tales to sell at various towns, but the price isn't listed.

Comment: Meta question about if it is legal and allowed to answer this: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9329/10642

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The price of a printing press is listed in *Adventurer's Armory*, on page 20, as 250 gp.  Note that if you are looking to mass-produce a book you will need 1 plate per page or your production rate will be much less than the 5 pages per minute version, and the press only comes with one.  Additional plates are "expensive and labor-intensive" to create.  No specific price is given, but it may well be close to 250 gp if the price of the rest of the machinery is negligible.